# How to Disable / Uninstall Adobe Flash from Windows Safari

Tags: flash, safari

**How can I disable Adobe Flash from Safari - but not my other browsers ??**

I can't even believe this... but - in complete opposite to the iPad - it looks like Apple did not make a way to disable Adobe Flash from Safari.

It is not listed under `Preferences > Extensions` and there is nothing related to Flash in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Safari` directory.

---

*Why?* - I want to 'simulate' an iPad as best as possible for testing with JWPlayer - which has an HTML 5 fallback mode. I'd also like to test other HTML fallback for Flash areas on my site, and dedicating a browser to this seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari on iPad and iPhone does not have the same behavior as Safari for Macs and PCs.  Even if you disable plugins you will not get the same results.  Also, performance on an iOS device will by far not be able to match that on a regular desktop or laptop computer.

So if you want to be sure, you will have to get an iPad for testing at some point.  But if you don't want to do that, I would suggest you prepare everything as thoroughly as possible, and then just waltz into an Apple Store and "test drive" one right there ;).

Having said that, I found a nice [source on how to prepare your apps for iPad](http://iphone.appstorm.net/roundups/developer/the-ipad-web-design-development-toolbox/), which contains a lot of helpful links, including a stencil eps for illustrator to help making your designs match the iPad webgrid.  There is an older [page for iPhone](http://iphone.appstorm.net/roundups/developer/the-complete-iphone-development-toolbox/), as well.

Comment: thanks for the extra info and ipad tips page. i have a couple friends with iPads but they never seem to be in Starbucks when i need them - and I want the damn thing to work before i embarass myself by asking the first person I see with an ipad to test a dead page :-) Safari at least lets me have an HTML5 only browser testbed - which I need anyway!

Comment: While informative, this doesn't actually address the question!

Comment: Actually, it does.  OP was trying to disable the Flash plug-in to simulate an iPad - I pointed out that there is no way to reliably do that, and that the only way to be sure that your app works on iPad is to use an actual device.

Answer (score 2):

Found something.... Under 'Advanced' there is an option 'Enable plug-ins' which disables all plug-ins.

Fortunately I'm not using any other plug-ins besides Flash - so this did the trick!

[image]

(couldn't find windows screenshot)